# Map Typescript generic array

Tags: arrays, typescript, generics

Suppose I have an object with a static set of keys, and then a type specifying a subset of those keys as a static array:

```
const myBigStaticObject = {
  key1: () => 'foo',
  key2: () => 'bar',
  // ...
  keyN: () => 'fooN',
}

type BigObject = typeof myBigStaticObject

type Keys = ['key2', 'keyN']
```

Is there a nice way of then programmatically creating a mapped type which takes `Keys` as its generic argument, i.e. does the following:

```
type ObjectValueFromKeys<K extends (keyof BigObject)[]> = // ???

// such that:

ObjectValueFromKeys<Keys> = [() => 'bar', () => 'fooN']
```

The equivalent for objects here would be:

```
const objectKeys = {
  a1: 'key2';
  a2: 'keyN';
}

type ObjectValueFromObjectKeys<M extends Record<string, keyof BigObject>> = {
  [K in keyof M]: BigObject[M[K]]
}

// then

type ObjectValueFromObjectKeys<typeof objectKeys> = {
  a1: () => 'bar';
  a2: () => 'fooN';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not know this but you can actually use a mapped type with arrays and tuples while still retaining the array/tuple type in the output!

That means you can use something like this, where it checks if the value is a key of the big object first:

```
type ObjectValueFromKeys<K extends (keyof BigObject)[]> = {
    [P in keyof K]: K[P] extends keyof BigObject ? BigObject[K[P]] : K[P];
};
```

And it works like a charm:

```
type T1 = ObjectValueFromKeys<["key2", "keyN"]>;
//   ^? [() => "bar", () => "fooN"]
```

Don't believe me? [See for yourself.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=8#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwEIEsDmBlKBDKLgDyARgFYCmwsAvDAN4CwAUDDANZkICMAXDABQBKGFQB8MAOQAzECHExsEGKEhQANExbsEAJl6DhY8UWwAnOQqXho65jAD0dmADoXGthwByeoaInSQHuaKytZMAL4A3ExMUAgADmQwqGjE5JTCMLEJIJLwyOhYuPipFFBRjDHxiSWUAGrYADYArmQAYiYgcADSHBAAPF0wZAAeUGRgACaKfFo5Seg1UAIA2gC6YjQMtizLAAowKGDuCHNdq7xde6tDo+NTx3PJizAA-PMppKXLl7ur1xdXcqRaKMLKJAAqnAyi3qzTaHW6vT6ywARFptCjVDA0Z4Uetyg4WDAAHovIA)

You will probably notice that there is `as const` used in the big object:

```
    key1: () => 'foo' as const,
```

This is because, for some reason, TypeScript can't deduce that this function can *only* return `"foo"`. And so I have used `as const` to make it return the literal `"foo"` for our case so we can see if the solution works.